# How can I update an element in a tuple list?

Tags: haskell, recursion, option-type

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to update an element in a tuple list. My tuple list is of type `[(String, Int)]`, I only want to decrement the integer by -1 if the string I get is in the list, otherwise I have to return Nothing, i try to do:

```
myFunc :: String -> [(String, Int)] -> Maybe [(String, Int)]
myFunc s [] = Nothing 
myFunc s ((s2,i):xs)
           | s == s2 = Just ((s2, i - 1) : xs)
           | otherwise = myFunc s xs
```

For example, if I have `[("l1",10), ("l2",20), ("l3",30)]` and want update "l2", the function had to return `[("l1",10), ("l2",19), ("l3",30)]`, but my function return `[("l2",19), ("l3",30)]`

Comment: You need to explain more so that we can help you

Comment: 1. In the `otherwise` branch you are not using `(s2,i)`, perhaps think where you should add it. 2. `Maybe [...]` usually doesn't make a lot of sense. Why not just return an empty list?

Comment: `otherwise = myFunc s xs` discards the first element of the list, the `(s2,i)`

Comment: Is there a practical purpose for returning `Nothing` instead of an unmodified list when the key is missing, or is this just an artificial homework assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
| otherwise = myFunc s xs
```

Here, we discard the first element of the list. That's likely not what you intended. Consider

```
| otherwise = fmap ((s2, i) :) $ myFunc s xs
```

If we don't get a match, we don't want to throw the element out; we want to leave it in the list unmodified. Hence, we run the recursive call and then prepend the current element back on, untouched.

If you're coming from a more imperative language, you might worry that this function isn't tail recursive, which is fair. Your original function is tail recursive but this one is not. See [the Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tail_recursion) for a good explanation as to why we generally don't care in Haskell.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but i did it and returns this error ,`Couldn't match expected type: [(String, Int)] with actual type: Maybe [(String, Int)]`, this type maybe is kind of confusing

Comment: Oops, didn't see the `Maybe`. An `fmap` will fix that right up. See my edit.